# How can I optimize the below code which executes 700 times in a loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Loop starts like this :

```
   FOR z in 1 .. val LOOP  --val is some variable

    select add_months(p_in_usageMonth, - (z - 1))
      INTO v_usage_month
      from dual; ---simple select


    select count(*)
      into n_invoice_exists
      from fmo_op2_invoice inv
     where inv.usage_month = v_usage_month
       and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
       and inv.invoice_status_id =
           (select status_seq_id
              from fmo_op2_status
             where status_type = 'INVOICE'
               and fmo_op2_status.status_description = 'SUCCESS')
       and invoice_num not in
           (select NVL(rev.cancelled_invoice_number, 'X')
              from fmo_op2_invoice rev)
       and NVL(engine_serial_number, '%') like NVL(p_in_esn, '%')
       and inv.billing_invoice_type not in ('C', 'M', 'R');


    IF n_invoice_exists = 0 THEN
```

--index in fmo_op2_contract table-
--UNIQUE- ONPOINT_CONTRACT_NUMBER, CONTRACT_SEQ_ID, CONTRACT_NAME
--NORMAL- FIN_SSO, CONTRACT_SEQ_ID,CONTRACT_SEQ_ID

```
      IF upper(p_in_billingType) = 'POPULAR' or
         upper(p_in_billingType) = 'RESTORED' THEN
        SELECT UPPER(nvl(usage_type_popular,
                         fmo_op2_contract.usage_type_restored)),
               UPPER(nvl(fmo_op2_contract.usage_category_popular,
                         fmo_op2_contract.usage_category_restored))
          INTO v_usage_type, v_usage_category
          FROM fmo_op2_contract
         WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId;

        IF v_usage_type = 'ENGINE' THEN

          if p_in_esn is null then
            v_engine_serial_number := '%';
          else
            v_engine_serial_number := p_in_esn;
          end if;
```

--index on fmo_op2_invoice
--UNIQUE-INVOICE_NUM

```
          select count(*)
            into v_tot
            from (select distinct invoice_num
                    from fmo_op2_invoice inv
                   where inv.usage_month = v_usage_month
                     and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                     and inv.invoice_status_id =
                         (select status_seq_id
                            from fmo_op2_status
                           where status_type = 'INVOICE'
                             and fmo_op2_status.status_description =
                                 'SUCCESS')
                     and invoice_num not in
                         (select NVL(rev.cancelled_invoice_number, 'X')
                            from fmo_op2_invoice rev)
                     and NVL(engine_serial_number, '%') like
                         v_engine_serial_number);

          IF v_tot > 0 THEN
            select distinct invoice_num
              INTO v_inv_num
              from fmo_op2_invoice inv
             where inv.usage_month = v_usage_month
               and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
               and inv.invoice_status_id =
                   (select status_seq_id
                      from fmo_op2_status
                     where status_type = 'INVOICE'
                       and fmo_op2_status.status_description = 'SUCCESS')
               and invoice_num not in
                   (select NVL(rev.cancelled_invoice_number, 'X')
                      from fmo_op2_invoice rev)
               and NVL(engine_serial_number, '%') like
                   v_engine_serial_number;

            SELECT COUNT(*)
              INTO v_inv_exists
              FROM (SELECT *
                      from fmo_op2_invoice
                     WHERE invoice_num = v_inv_num);



            IF v_inv_exists > 0 THEN
              --if inv present

              SELECT COUNT(*)
                INTO v_cancelled
                FROM (SELECT *
                        FROM fmo_op2_invoice a, fmo_op2_status b
                       WHERE a.cancelled_invoice_number = v_inv_num
                         AND a.invoice_status_id = b.status_seq_id
                         AND b.status_code = 'S');

              IF v_cancelled = 0 THEN
                RAISE ex_custom;
              END IF;
            END IF;
          END IF;

          DELETE FROM fmo_op2_engine_usage_factors
           WHERE usage_month = v_usage_month
             and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId;

          DELETE FROM fmo_op2_engine_usage
           WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
             and usage_month = v_usage_month
         AND upper(usage_category)<>'BASL';
```

---calling another procedure in loop.
              save_engine_utilization_prc(p_in_contractId,
                                          p_in_billingType,
                                          v_usage_month,
                                          p_in_esn,
                                          p_in_util_data_list,
                                          p_in_fact_avg_list,
                                          p_in_login_id,
                                          val,
                                          z,
                                          p_out_success_status,
                                          p_out_esn_check_fails,
                                          p_out_error);

```
          SELECT v_i - 1 INTO p_out_count FROM DUAL;

        ELSIF v_usage_type = 'FLEET' THEN

          select count(*)
            into v_tot
            from (select distinct invoice_num
                    FROM fmo_op2_fleet_usage
                   WHERE trim(subfleet_id) in
                         (select subfleet_id
                            from fmo_op2_fleet e
                           where e.contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                             and e.valid_ind = 'Y')
                     and usage_month = v_usage_month
                     and invoice_num is not null
                     and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId);

          IF v_tot > 0 THEN
            -- tot invoice
            select distinct invoice_num
              INTO v_inv_num
              FROM fmo_op2_fleet_usage
             WHERE trim(subfleet_id) in
                   (select subfleet_id
                      from fmo_op2_fleet e
                     where e.contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                       and e.valid_ind = 'Y'

                    )
               and usage_month = v_usage_month
               and invoice_num is not null
               and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId;

            SELECT COUNT(*)
              INTO v_inv_exists
              FROM (SELECT *
                      from fmo_op2_invoice
                     WHERE invoice_num = v_inv_num);

            IF v_inv_exists > 0 THEN


              SELECT COUNT(*)
                INTO v_cancelled
                FROM (SELECT *
                        FROM fmo_op2_invoice a, fmo_op2_status b
                       WHERE a.cancelled_invoice_number = v_inv_num
                         AND a.invoice_status_id = b.status_seq_id
                         AND b.status_code = 'S');

              IF v_cancelled = 0 THEN
                RAISE ex_custom;
              END IF;
            END IF;
          END IF;

          DELETE FROM fmo_op2_fleet_usage_factors
           WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
             and usage_month = v_usage_month;

          DELETE FROM fmo_op2_fleet_usage
           WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
             and usage_month = v_usage_month
             and invoice_num is null; 
        ---another procedure call
          save_fleet_utilization_prc(p_in_contractId,
                                     p_in_billingType,
                                     v_usage_month,
                                     p_in_esn,
                                     p_in_util_data_list,
                                     p_in_fact_avg_list,
                                     p_in_login_id,
                                     val,
                                     z,
                                     p_out_success_status,
                                     p_out_esn_not_exists,
                                     p_out_esn_check_fails,
                                     p_out_error);

        ELSIF v_usage_type = 'TAIL' THEN

          select count(*)
            into v_tot
            from (select distinct invoice_num
                    FROM fmo_op2_tail_usage
                   WHERE trim(tail_number) in
                         (select tail_number
                            from fmo_op2_engine_master e
                           where e.contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                             and e.valid_ind = 'Y')
                     and usage_month = v_usage_month
                     and invoice_num is not null);

          IF v_tot > 0 THEN
            -- tot invoice
            select distinct invoice_num
              INTO v_inv_num
              FROM fmo_op2_tail_usage
             WHERE trim(subfleet_id) in
                   (select subfleet_id
                      from fmo_op2_fleet e
                     where e.contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                       and e.valid_ind = 'Y')
               and usage_month = v_usage_month
               and invoice_num is not null;

            SELECT COUNT(*)
              INTO v_inv_exists
              FROM (SELECT *
                      from fmo_op2_invoice
                     WHERE invoice_num = v_inv_num);

            IF v_inv_exists > 0 THEN
              --if inv present
```

--Index on fmo_op2_status 
--STATUS_SEQ_ID -UNIQUE

```
              SELECT COUNT(*)
                INTO v_cancelled
                FROM (SELECT *
                        FROM fmo_op2_invoice a, fmo_op2_status b
                       WHERE a.cancelled_invoice_number = v_inv_num
                         AND a.invoice_status_id = b.status_seq_id
                         AND b.status_code = 'S');

              IF v_cancelled = 0 THEN
                RAISE ex_custom;
              END IF;
            END IF;
          END IF;

          DELETE FROM fmo_op2_tail_usage_factors
           WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
             and usage_month = v_usage_month;

          DELETE FROM fmo_op2_tail_usage
           WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
             and usage_month = v_usage_month
             and invoice_num is null; 


          save_tail_utilization_prc(p_in_contractId,
                                    p_in_billingType,
                                    v_usage_month,
                                    p_in_esn,
                                    p_in_util_data_list,
                                    p_in_fact_avg_list,
                                    p_in_login_id,
                                    val,
                                    z,
                                    p_out_success_status,
                                    p_out_esn_not_exists,
                                    p_out_esn_check_fails,
                                    p_out_error);

          SELECT v_i - 1 INTO p_out_count FROM DUAL;
          SELECT v_j - 1 INTO p_out_check_fail_count FROM DUAL;



        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
```

--Record count is around 1500 in each table.
This loop executes 700 times and takes alot of time.
How can I optimize it ?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. How could we optimize something we don't know? Please post a relevant part of code. If you have some queries in the loop, please post the explain plan and the table structure, including indexes, and an approximated size of the involved tables

Comment: now that's better :)

Comment: one more thing, can you please add row counts about the used tables in the code too? And indexes if exist

Comment: done! Index column added for important tables. Record count in each table is around 1500.

Comment: Run it through [`dbms_profiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_profil.htm#ARPLS039) to find out which sections are taking the time. Does that first `fmo_opt2_invoice` query need to be inside the loop? I'd also make it an existence check rather than a full count.

Comment: Thanks William- Working on the same. Please suggest if you find some more time consuming issues.

Comment: There seem to be several places where you count the number of rows matching some condition and then do something if it's non-zero. It may be more efficient to rewrite these as `select from dual where exists (...)` or just add `and rownum = 1`. Also `not in (subquery)` plus a nullable key can lead to an inefficient execution plan, so consider adding some `and xyz is not null` conditions if that is the case.

Comment: The bigger issue might be the whole loop structure. Do you need to loop through a series of numbers, or could you drive it from the data itself? And does everything need to be in the loop? The `select from dual` to derive v_usage_month looks odd to me. (Might it be different each time? Why use a dummy query instead of just assigning the value?)

Answer (score 0):

there are some issue, i marked them inline:
one note first of all, you are using the core of the second query a lot, maybe you should consider to make a same query for a "bigger"
 resultset, however you would "calculate" it once. Or faster, see comments inline

```
FOR z in 1 .. val LOOP  --val is some variable


select add_months(p_in_usageMonth, - (z - 1))
  INTO v_usage_month
  from dual; ---simple select


select count(*)
  into n_invoice_exists
  from fmo_op2_invoice inv
 where inv.usage_month = v_usage_month
   and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
   and inv.invoice_status_id =               
       --issue No.1: remove that query from here and put it into a WITH or a subselect for a join
       (select status_seq_id
          from fmo_op2_status
         where status_type = 'INVOICE'
           and fmo_op2_status.status_description = 'SUCCESS')
       --issue No.2.: remove it too like above, using a left outer and an IS NULL condition in the where
   and invoice_num not in
       (select NVL(rev.cancelled_invoice_number, 'X')
          from fmo_op2_invoice rev)
       --issue No.3.: replace like to = , it's pointless to search with like and more expensive 
   and NVL(engine_serial_number, '%') like NVL(p_in_esn, '%')
   and inv.billing_invoice_type not in ('C', 'M', 'R');


IF n_invoice_exists = 0 THEN

  IF upper(p_in_billingType) = 'POPULAR' or
     upper(p_in_billingType) = 'RESTORED' THEN
    SELECT UPPER(nvl(usage_type_popular,
                     fmo_op2_contract.usage_type_restored)),
           UPPER(nvl(fmo_op2_contract.usage_category_popular,
                     fmo_op2_contract.usage_category_restored))
      INTO v_usage_type, v_usage_category
      FROM fmo_op2_contract
     WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId;

    IF v_usage_type = 'ENGINE' THEN

      if p_in_esn is null then
        v_engine_serial_number := '%';
      else
        v_engine_serial_number := p_in_esn;
      end if;

      select count(*)
        into v_tot
        from (
              --issue No.4.: replace distinct to "group by", 'cause group by using hash instead of expensive sorting of the distinct. And the rest issues are  the same like above
              select distinct invoice_num
                from fmo_op2_invoice inv
               where inv.usage_month = v_usage_month
                 and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                 and inv.invoice_status_id =
                     (select status_seq_id
                        from fmo_op2_status
                       where status_type = 'INVOICE'
                         and fmo_op2_status.status_description =
                             'SUCCESS')
                 and invoice_num not in
                     (select NVL(rev.cancelled_invoice_number, 'X')
                        from fmo_op2_invoice rev)
                 and NVL(engine_serial_number, '%') like
                     v_engine_serial_number);

      IF v_tot > 0 THEN
       --issue No.5.: see above
        select distinct invoice_num
          INTO v_inv_num
          from fmo_op2_invoice inv
         where inv.usage_month = v_usage_month
           and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
           and inv.invoice_status_id =
               (select status_seq_id
                  from fmo_op2_status
                 where status_type = 'INVOICE'
                   and fmo_op2_status.status_description = 'SUCCESS')
           and invoice_num not in
               (select NVL(rev.cancelled_invoice_number, 'X')
                  from fmo_op2_invoice rev)
           and NVL(engine_serial_number, '%') like
               v_engine_serial_number;

        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO v_inv_exists
          FROM (SELECT *
                  from fmo_op2_invoice
                 WHERE invoice_num = v_inv_num);


        IF v_inv_exists > 0 THEN
          --if inv present

          SELECT COUNT(*)
            INTO v_cancelled
            FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM fmo_op2_invoice a, fmo_op2_status b
                   WHERE a.cancelled_invoice_number = v_inv_num
                     AND a.invoice_status_id = b.status_seq_id
                     AND b.status_code = 'S');

          IF v_cancelled = 0 THEN
            RAISE ex_custom;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;

      DELETE FROM fmo_op2_engine_usage_factors
       WHERE usage_month = v_usage_month
         and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId;

      DELETE FROM fmo_op2_engine_usage
       WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
         and usage_month = v_usage_month
     AND upper(usage_category)<>'BASL';


save_engine_utilization_prc(p_in_contractId, p_in_billingType, v_usage_month, p_in_esn, p_in_util_data_list, p_in_fact_avg_list, p_in_login_id, val, z, p_out_success_status, p_out_esn_check_fails, p_out_error);

      --issue No.6.: avoiding unnecessary context switching, replace that stmt to a simple  p_out_count := v_i -1 ;
      SELECT v_i - 1 INTO p_out_count FROM DUAL;

    ELSIF v_usage_type = 'FLEET' THEN
      --issue No.7.: just like above
      select count(*)
        into v_tot
        from (select distinct invoice_num
                FROM fmo_op2_fleet_usage
               WHERE trim(subfleet_id) in
                     (select subfleet_id
                        from fmo_op2_fleet e
                       where e.contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                         and e.valid_ind = 'Y')
                 and usage_month = v_usage_month
                 and invoice_num is not null
                 and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId);

      IF v_tot > 0 THEN
        -- tot invoice
        --issue No.8.: same
        select distinct invoice_num
          INTO v_inv_num
          FROM fmo_op2_fleet_usage
         WHERE trim(subfleet_id) in
               (select subfleet_id
                  from fmo_op2_fleet e
                 where e.contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                   and e.valid_ind = 'Y'

                )
           and usage_month = v_usage_month
           and invoice_num is not null
           and contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId;

        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO v_inv_exists
          FROM (SELECT *
                  from fmo_op2_invoice
                 WHERE invoice_num = v_inv_num);

        IF v_inv_exists > 0 THEN


          SELECT COUNT(*)
            INTO v_cancelled
            FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM fmo_op2_invoice a, fmo_op2_status b
                   WHERE a.cancelled_invoice_number = v_inv_num
                     AND a.invoice_status_id = b.status_seq_id
                     AND b.status_code = 'S');

          IF v_cancelled = 0 THEN
            RAISE ex_custom;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;

      DELETE FROM fmo_op2_fleet_usage_factors
       WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
         and usage_month = v_usage_month;

      DELETE FROM fmo_op2_fleet_usage
       WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
         and usage_month = v_usage_month
         and invoice_num is null; 

      save_fleet_utilization_prc(p_in_contractId,
                                 p_in_billingType,
                                 v_usage_month,
                                 p_in_esn,
                                 p_in_util_data_list,
                                 p_in_fact_avg_list,
                                 p_in_login_id,
                                 val,
                                 z,
                                 p_out_success_status,
                                 p_out_esn_not_exists,
                                 p_out_esn_check_fails,
                                 p_out_error);

    ELSIF v_usage_type = 'TAIL' THEN

      --issue No.9.: same
      select count(*)
        into v_tot
        from (select distinct invoice_num
                FROM fmo_op2_tail_usage
               WHERE trim(tail_number) in
                     (select tail_number
                        from fmo_op2_engine_master e
                       where e.contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                         and e.valid_ind = 'Y')
                 and usage_month = v_usage_month
                 and invoice_num is not null);

      IF v_tot > 0 THEN
        -- tot invoice
        --issue No.10.: same
        select distinct invoice_num
          INTO v_inv_num
          FROM fmo_op2_tail_usage
         WHERE trim(subfleet_id) in
               (select subfleet_id
                  from fmo_op2_fleet e
                 where e.contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
                   and e.valid_ind = 'Y')
           and usage_month = v_usage_month
           and invoice_num is not null;

        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO v_inv_exists
          FROM (SELECT *
                  from fmo_op2_invoice
                 WHERE invoice_num = v_inv_num);

        IF v_inv_exists > 0 THEN
          --if inv present


          SELECT COUNT(*)
            INTO v_cancelled
            FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM fmo_op2_invoice a, fmo_op2_status b
                   WHERE a.cancelled_invoice_number = v_inv_num
                     AND a.invoice_status_id = b.status_seq_id
                     AND b.status_code = 'S');

          IF v_cancelled = 0 THEN
            RAISE ex_custom;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;

      DELETE FROM fmo_op2_tail_usage_factors
       WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
         and usage_month = v_usage_month;

      DELETE FROM fmo_op2_tail_usage
       WHERE contract_seq_id = p_in_contractId
         and usage_month = v_usage_month
         and invoice_num is null; 


      save_tail_utilization_prc(p_in_contractId,
                                p_in_billingType,
                                v_usage_month,
                                p_in_esn,
                                p_in_util_data_list,
                                p_in_fact_avg_list,
                                p_in_login_id,
                                val,
                                z,
                                p_out_success_status,
                                p_out_esn_not_exists,
                                p_out_esn_check_fails,
                                p_out_error);
      ----issue No.11.: avoid contextswitching 
      SELECT v_i - 1 INTO p_out_count FROM DUAL;
      SELECT v_j - 1 INTO p_out_check_fail_count FROM DUAL;



    END IF;
  END IF;
END IF;

END LOOP;
```

and last for last, i would check the exec.time of the DELETE stms's too.